# Handling secretly changed API in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, internationalization, chinese-locale

I had made a Chrome extension, and recently an update of Chrome broke some of my code. I found out that they have secretly changed the behavior of [`.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) (thanks for making it harder Google). Before the update to Chrome 38, this code returns the number of the current year according to the Chinese calendar, which is `31` (~the year 2014-2015 in the Gregorian Calendar):

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat("zh-TW-u-ca-chinese",{year:"numeric"}).format(new Date()); //31年
```

Since in [the Chinese numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagenary_cycle), base-10 is used for the 10-th place and base-12 is used for the 1-st place, to convert the number 31 to Chinese numbering, this code is used:

```
var y = +Intl.DateTimeFormat("zh-TW-u-ca-chinese",{year:"numeric"}).format(date).match(/\d+/)[0],
    天干 = ["甲","乙","丙","丁","戊","己","庚","辛","壬","癸"],            //base 10
    地支 = ["子","丑","寅","卯","辰","巳","午","未","申","酉","戌","亥"];  //base 12

y = 天干[(y-1)%10] + 地支[(y-1)%12];     //甲午
```

But now, instead of returning the number, Chrome *automatically* did all the conversion for me. And now the returned value is just `"甲午年"`, which breaks my code, specifically this part:

```
.match(/\d+/)[0]
```

I cannot just remove the manual conversion I had, since not every user will be using the latest version of Chrome. What is a good way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple test whether the return value contains a digit before attempting a conversion (or conversely, check whether the return value looks like a valid date format before trying to extract a digit):

```
var y = +Intl.DateTimeFormat("zh-TW-u-ca-chinese",{year:"numeric"}).format(date);
if (/\d/.test(y)) {
    y = y.match(/\d+/)[0];
    var 天干 = ["甲","乙","丙","丁","戊","己","庚","辛","壬","癸"];            //base 10
    var 地支 = ["子","丑","寅","卯","辰","巳","午","未","申","酉","戌","亥"];  //base 12
    y = 天干[(y-1)%10] + 地支[(y-1)%12];     //甲午
}
```

Whenever you encounter a problem that cannot be detected in this way, then you could try to determine in which version of Chrome the change was introduced, and extract the Chrome version from `navigator.userAgent` for comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to apply this method to the month and day as well. However I'll need to do some adjustment since it messes up my leap month calculation.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 If the change is intentional (i.e. the old behavior was faulty, and the update corrected it), then I suggest to update your code to use the new behavior and implement a *polyfill* to add the "new" behavior to old versions of Chrome. This keeps your code base relatively clean, and makes it easier to remove the legacy code when you decide to not support certain versions of Chrome any more.

Comment: The polyfill idea is a really great suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you point out, `match(/\d+/)` fails. Branch on that.

You can do the following:

```
var x = Intl.DateTimeFormat("zh-TW-u-ca-chinese",{year:"numeric"}).format(date);
if(x.match(/\d+/)){
  var y = +x.match(/\d+/)[0];
  /* old logic */
} else {
  /* new logic */
}
```

---

Or, alternatively, push an update with `"minimum_chrome_version" : "38"` in the manifest. Users running older versions should stay with the older extensions.

Comment: Bumping `"minimum_chrome_version"` is quite a drastic measure to counter something that can as easily be fixed as in the example. Nevertheless, +1 because it is not always possible to easily counter such incompatible API changes. PS. `.test` is a method of a regexp, not of a string, so you should swap the operands in the if-condition.

Comment: @RobW I'll just change it back to `match` :) And that's why I mentioned `"minimum_chrome_version"`, it's an overkill here but may be useful for others